# PHP include Variable Fail

Tags: php, variables, include

PHP include Variable Fail.
So i have problem with php variable inclusion, in php files where i need to call for specific variable in another php file, i dont always get the requested variable. And i dont understand why.

settings.php

```
<?php
$symbol = 'MUSIC';
$key='xxx';
$secret='xxx';
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
include ('settings.php');


function selected($key, $secret){
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://something.com?key='.$key.'&symbol='.$symbol.'&nonce='.$nonce; //Problem is in here


$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$secret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
$info = $obj["result"]["info"];
return $info;
```

info.php

```
<?php include "balancedb.php"; 

$url = "https://somthingother.com/";
$fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

$info = selected($key, $secret);
    echo "<br>".$symbol."-----------------".$info."<br>";

?>
```

I get Notice: "Undefined variable: symbol in ..\database.php on line 7"
"MUSIC-----------------"

In one place it takes tha variable but in other it doesnt. Why? How to fix that?

Comment: Some sensible indention and formatting would make this code much easier to read, and in turn, easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: $nonce=time(); Its is  declared in function.

Comment: $uri="https://something.com?key='$key'&symbol='$symbol'&nonce='$nonce'";

Comment: how are you using the GET arrays? Check if all are set/not empty.

Comment: the selected function is being called from inside the balancedb.php file, is the settings.php file being included inn to this file?

Comment: you also seem to be using this with a database, so if you're not showing relevant code for this, we can't help you. How is `info.php` include/used also? and what is `balancedb.php`?

Comment: `function selected($key, $secret, $symbol){` and `$info = selected($key, $secret, $symbol);`

Comment: @Federkun funny you should post that ^, I deleted the first comment I posted about using 2 arguments in the method, rather than 3. I shouldn't  have deleted it.

Comment: function selected($key, $secret) re-declares the $key, $secret variable, which are being passed to it from elsewhere. including the secrets file above the function definition would be irrelevant!

Comment: @user3633383 Right, to which I posted a comment about it most likely related to database work, which we don't know how it's used. The question is unclear for me. I think they're missing an argument in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You don't have access to `settings.php`'s `$symbol` (global scope) inside `selected`.

What to do? Pass it as an argument:

```
function selected($key, $secret, $symbol) {
```

Then when you call it

```
// pass settings.php's $symbol here
$info = selected($key, $secret, $symbol);
```

For more information, read the documentation about how the scope of a variable works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 include_once( "settings.php" ); //this must be included here, before calling the selected($key, $secret); function below!!!

 include_once( "balancedb.php" ); 

 $url = "https://somthingother.com/";
 $fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

 $info = selected($key, $secret);
 echo "<br>".$symbol."-----------------".$info."<br>";

 ?>
```